# Arange page with pictures and dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, position, center

i want to know haw can I put things (pic, menu, text, etc) in the center of browser.
I want to put from top to botom :
1. the image banner 
2. the menu
3. some text 
Unfortunately, I desinged the drop-down-menu and it's on the left of page, and If I try tu put it in the center of page , the submenus won't work ( nav ul { left:20%}).I tried to put the image above it and could't do it.
What are my options? Thank's in advance! 
these are my codes:
CSS

```
html, body {
width: 100%; 
margin: 0;
}


div ul ul {
display: none;
}

div ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

div ul {
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CCFF66 0%, #99CC66 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top, #CCFF66 0%, #99CC66 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CCFF66 0%, #99CC66 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CCFF66 0%, #99CC66 100%);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
div ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
div ul li {
float: left;
}
div ul li:hover {
    background:#CC3366;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFCCFF 0%, #CC3366 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFCCFF 0%, #CC3366 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFCCFF 0%, #CC3366 40%);
}
    div ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

div ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 5px 55px;
    color: #757575; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

div ul ul {
background: #99CC66; border-radius: 0; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
div ul ul li {
    float:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    position:relative;
}
    div ul ul li a {
        padding: 5px 35px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        div ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #CC3366;
        }

div ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;

}

#wrap {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Acasa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">An I</a>
        <ul id="an3">
            <li><a href="#">Semestrul I</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">IP Istoria Psihologiei</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="an1s1ip1.zip">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">PG Psihologie Generala</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">NP Neuropsihologie</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">PCA Psihologia Dezvoltarii</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">IE Inteligenta Emotionala</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Semestrul II</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Materia 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">materia 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Materia 3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Materia 4</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Materia 5</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
    <li><a href="#">An II</a>
        <ul id="an2">
            <li><a href="#">Semestrul I</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">an2 sem1 Materia 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an2 sem1 Materia 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an2 sem1 Materia 3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an2 sem1 Materia 4</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an2 sem1 Materia 5</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Semestrul II</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">an2 sem2 Materia 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an2 sem2 Materia 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an2 sem2 Materia 3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an2 sem2 Materia 4</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an2 sem2 Materia 5</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
    <li><a href="#">An III</a>
        <ul id="an1">
            <li><a href="#">Semestrul I</a>
                <ul id="an1sem2">
                    <li><a href="#">an3 sem1 Materia 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an3 sem1 Materia 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an3 sem1 Materia 3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an3 sem1 Materia 4</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an3 sem1 Materia 5</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Semestrul II</a>
                <ul id="an1se1">
                    <li><a href="#">an3 sem2 Materia 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an3 sem2 Materia 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an3 sem2 Materia 3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an3 sem2 Materia 4</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">an3 sem2 Materia 5</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Curs 13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">referate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Diverse</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did the center tags work for you???

Comment: yes it did. Thank's alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<center></center>` I think is what you are looking for, use at the start of your html and at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add a wrap around your content and add

```
html, body {
    width:100%; 
    margin:0; /* for consistency */
    }

#wrap {
    width:753px; /* width of your nav bar */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franvarn/ZTX39/)

Also, the center tag is deprecated (and not supported in html5) so don't use that.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I think I messed something up, it didn't work out

Comment: Haha. Don't worry. We've all been there. I can't tell you how many times I've asked dumb questions!

Comment: So , I have edited the code I posted the first time with the changes you told me, maybe I am doing something wrong because is not working. Thanks again for the teaching :)